# Why does my system tray Wi-Fi icon keep flashing from white to grey in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

Why does the Wi-Fi icon in my system tray icons area go from white (as it is normally) to grey (completely grey, no asterisk or anything next to it, just greyed out) again and again? It's been happening for a few weeks, and hasn't happened before. My Wi-Fi connection is fine, but has been a bit slow at times. Could someone please tell me what it means; I can't find any answers on the internet or Microsoft's website.

Thanks :D

Comment: Your WiFi connection is breaking off at times. You might want to check a few things in your WiFi adapters properties (via Control Panel > Network/Internet > Network and sharing > Change adapter settings, right-click on your WiFi adapter icon, then Properties): click on the Configure button, go to Power settings, and uncheck the two boxes under "Allow this computer to disable this device to save power" if they're checked. In the Advanced tab, set Roaming sensitivity to "Low" or "Lowest", Leisure power save to "Disabled", Preamble mode to "Short & Long".

Comment: Going grey without astrerix means it is still connected, but the reception is very low. You may have to check for a driver update to fix this, or restart your Wifi router or wifi access point.

Comment: Then, still in Control Panel, but in System and security > Power options, click on "Edit parameters..." for your current power plan, then on "Edit advanced parameters...", under "Wireless parameters", make sure your AC and DC settings are on "Maximum performance".

Comment: My network adapter driver is the latest version, and I have restarted my router, but the problem continues to persist.

Comment: I'm trying Didier's advice

Comment: Sadly, none of the advice I could try worked, and I couldn't find 'roaming sensitivity' or 'preamble mode' in the advanced tab of the network adapter configuration settings.

Comment: Do you have any other advice, @Didier or @LPChip?

Comment: If you know any solutions, please help, now I'm actually starting to LOSE connection.

Comment: Click on the link under your connection in Control Panel; it'll open a property window that gives you signal strength, among other things. If you download speed seems normal (e.g. 72Mbps for a WiFi b/g adapter), but a weak signal, it means you have to get closer to the access point, or buy a repeater that will enhance the AP's original signal in the part of the house you're in.

Comment: Ok, so when the icon is white, the speed is 72mbps (as you said). But when it's grey, the speed is 144kbps!

Comment: It keeps losing signal again and again @Didier

Comment: From 144 kbps to 72mbps in a loop that will go on for the rest of eternity

Comment: Have you tried using a different channel?

Comment: You have to determine if it's the access point whose signal is fluctuating, or your WiFi card who's losing steam at a more or less regular interval. If you sit right in front of the router, do you still get signal loss? If so, it might be your router's fault. If the signal is strong, it's your WiFi card's.

Comment: As far as all the other devices in my household are concerned, the router is working fine. @Didier

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'channel'? @DavidPostill

Comment: Here's what you can try: open Device Manager, locate your WiFi card in the Network section, right-click on it, and choose "Uninstall this device". If prompted to delete the driver as well, check that box, and confirm your choice, then restart your PC. Once it has restarted, go back to Device Manager, right-click on the WiFi card line, and choose to enable it again. Windows will reinstall the driver, and you should be able to connect to your home network. Then we'll see if the problem persists.

Comment: [Why Channels 1, 6, and 11? | MetaGeek](https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html)

Comment: Hold on a sec... I'll try

Comment: Ok, I've tried, but I'll monitor the Wi-Fi for a bit to make sure the problem has gone.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have no idea what Wi-Fi channel I'm on

Comment: My router is a 2.4Ghz router though

Comment: @Didier Thanks for that, the problem seems to have been resolved, but I'll refer back to here if it returns.

Comment: OK, that's good! It was probably a driver issue all along, as mentioned by @LPChip. WiFi problems are always hard to troubleshoot, there's so many different places to look into.

Comment: Yep, it seems that there's an issue with the latest driver update for my network adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Here's what you can try: open Device Manager, locate your WiFi card in the Network section, right-click on it, and choose "Uninstall this device". If prompted to delete the driver as well, check that box, and confirm your choice, then restart your PC. Once it has restarted, go back to Device Manager, right-click on the WiFi card line, and choose to enable it again. Windows will reinstall the driver, and you should be able to connect to your home network. Then we'll see if the problem persists." – Didier

(This comment seemed to help me: thanks to Didier)